# c# Interop.Word Find.Execute inside of a textbox in word doc

Tags: c#, ms-word

I am using the FindAndReplace like built in function to replace some text in a word document with a new one. But when the wanted text is inside a textbox the function can't seems to find it.

my code:

```
object matchCase = true;
object matchWholeWord = true;
object matchWildCards = false;
object matchSoundLike = false;
object nmatchAllforms = false;
object forward = true;
object format = true;
object matchKashida = false;
object matchDiactitics = false;
object matchAlefHamza = false;
object matchControl = false;
object read_only = false;
object visible = true;
object replace = 2;
object wrap = 1;

var range = myWordDoc.Range();

//Finds the parameter, then replaces
range.Find.Execute("replaceable",
ref matchCase, ref matchWholeWord,
ref matchWildCards, ref matchSoundLike,
ref nmatchAllforms, ref forward,
ref wrap, ref format, "value",
ref replace, ref matchKashida,
ref matchDiactitics, ref matchAlefHamza,
ref matchControl);
```

There is an option to go over all the textboxs in the file and calling the function on the internal text?
(without actually replacing the whole text inside with a new one like so:)

```
shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = resultingText;
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `shape.TextFrame.TextRange` returns a `Range` object, so loop the `Shapes` in the document, test whether the type is a text box, then

```
var rngTextBox = shape.TextFrame.TextRange;

//Finds the parameter, then replaces
rngTextBox.Find.Execute("replaceable", //etc.
```